# Group by with calendar quarter as column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1111

I want the sum of one column of my table, grouped by calendar quarter. To be more specific, what I have now is the sum of the column I want month by month:

```
select month(emitido_date) as mes, year(emitido_date) as ano, ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100)),0) as totaliva
from documento as doc
inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
where serie.documento_categoria_id = 2 or  serie.documento_categoria_id = 3
group by mes, ano 
order by mes, ano desc
```

The code above is fine and works for me. It returns the sum of the column I want group by months. E.g.: **January:** 100, **February:** 200, **March:** 300. That's it until December.

My question is how to do this sum grouped by calendar quarter. To be specific, and looking for the example above, now I want to create a query which gives me the sum of values of [January, February, March]=600, [April, May, June], [July, August, September], [October, November, December]. I tried to do with the code below but I got an error:

> 1111 - invalid use of group function.

```
select 
sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (1,2,3) then ifnull(sum(det.quantidade),0) else 0 end) as Tri1,
sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (4,5,6) then ifnull(sum(det.quantidade),0) else 0 end) as Tri2,
    select 
    sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (1,2,3) then ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100)),0) else 0 end) as Tri1,
    sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (4,5,6) then ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100)),0) else 0 end) as Tri2,
    sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (7,8,9) then ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100)),0) else 0 end) as Tri3,
    sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (10,11,12) then ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100)),0) else 0 end) as Tri4,
    year(emitido_date) as ano
    from documento as doc
    inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
    inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
    inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
    where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3 
    group by year(emitido_date)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't know what 3 in 3 months means. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: "3 in 3 months" means the sum of one column in the periods: [Jan,mar],[apr,jun],[jul,sept],[oct,dec]

Comment: "3 in 3" is not how you say that in English. In this context it translates to "3 **by** 3 months", which is hard to combine in a sentence with "group by". A better way to say it might be "group by quarter".

Comment: Sorry about my English. I had already edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try `GROUP BY year(emitido_date)` instead of `group by ano`.

Also replace `ifnull(sum(det.quantidade),0)` with  `ifnull(det.quantidade,0)` as you already have `SUM` outside of `CASE` clause

Comment: And if my sum was 'ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100)),0) as totaliva' ?

Comment: If this worked for you and you don't get an error any more, I suggest you ask a new question on how to convert the query to use a new formula.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest aggregation functions.  But you don't need to.  I think you want:

```
select sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (1, 2,3 )
                then det.quantidade else 0 end) as Tri1,
       sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (4, 5, 6)
                then det.quantidade else 0 end) as Tri2,
       sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (7, 8, 9)
                then det.quantidade else 0 end) as Tri3,
       sum(case when month(emitido_date) in (10, 11, 12)
                then det.quantidade else 0 end) as Tri4,
       year(emitido_date) as ano
```

Comment: i just put de sum(det.quantidade) to make the question cleaner. The sum I want is: 'ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100)),0) as totaliva'

Comment: @HugoMachado . . . We can only answer the question being asked.  If you have another question, then you should ask another question.  Be sure it is the one you want an answer to, and sample data and desired results help convey what you want.